# Can we use webpack to decide which components should be served in app using business configuration at the build time?

Tags: angular, webpack

I am building an Angular app. There are hundreds of components in our component library. I want to load specific components for specific clients. Instead of writing the logic in code and rendering those components according to business configurations, it will be great if I can use business configurations at the build time and decide what components are required for a specific client.

Consider I have clients A, B who respectively using components x,y,z and p,y,z. A and B have independent deployments. Can I build a package that will be serving A and B independently using a webpack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.
There are several techniques to achieve that:

1. `File replacements`

For example you have `components.module.ts` something like this:

```
@NgModule({
 declarations() {
  XComponent,
  YComponent,
  ZComponent,
 }
})
class ComponentsModule{}
```

And it will be used for client `A`.
Then you should create file `components-b.module.ts` which contains following (name of module class should be the same, but filename can be different):

```
@NgModule({
 declarations() {
  PComponent,
  YComponent,
  ZComponent,
 }
})
class ComponentsModule{}
```

To apply file replacement you should to add a custom configuration to your `angular.json`:

```
 "configurations": {
  "production": {
    ...
  },
  "clientB": {
    "fileReplacements": [{
      "from": "path/to/components.module.ts",
      "to": "path/to/components-b.module.ts"
    }]
   }
```

And run it: `ng serve --configurateion=clientB`
Please note: angular team recommends to create different projects for different clients, not configurations.

2. `Webpack aliases`
   Almost the same as first approach but from different side.
   You can use `customWebpackConfig` property and get your own webpack config.
   In this config you can define aliases:

```
    {
     resolve: {
      alias: {
       '@myAliasToComponentsModule': client === 'A' ? 'path/to/moduleA' : 'path/to/moduleB';
      }
     }
    }
```

and then use it like that in your application:
`import { ComponentsModule } from '@myAliasToComponentsModule'`

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will definitely try both the approaches.